# json_decode and syntax in php

Tags: json

I have a problem with a json reading

I use this for read my json :

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
```

Here's my json :

```
{"metadata":
{
"name":"OurDatabase",
"articles":[

{"id":1,
"url":"http://www.google.com","title":"google.com",
"image":"http://www.oursite/e34ffadf12cd303dc7ba7e4a.jpg",
"category":[3]},

{"id":2,
"url":"http://www.google.com","title":"google.com",
"image":"http://www.oursite/e34ffadf12cd303dc7ba7e4a.jpg",
"category":[6]}
]
}
```

I have try multiple combinaison to recover the title and the id of each articles : 
I think i'm close...

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
      $id = $data[0]['articles'][$i]['id'];
 $titre = $data[$i]['articles']['articles'][0]['title'];
}
```

But.. nothing work... Can you help me ?
Many thanks

Comment: Wrong use of foreach, Invalid JSON -> http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an extra `}` at the end of your JSON file.
Then in PHP

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data->metadata->articles as $aArticle) {
  echo $aArticle->title . ", ";
}
?>
```